# "Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" Laravel conection from virtual machine

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine, laravel-5.6, connection-refused

I have Laravel 5.6 and try to connect to MySql from my virtual machine, but it gives to this error when I try "php artisan migrate":

"Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"

My configuration is good because  I can do it from host, but I can´t from my virtual machine.

Mysql user have all permissions, and I have this configuration:
 confing/database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

config.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=(myIp like x.x.x.x)
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=DB_laravel
DB_USERNAME=DB_laravel
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
```